# How to create a portfolio command in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So, I need to make a !vx portfolio command for my VX Helper Bot, I want it to send a link of the member of my team, example - `!vx portfolio videro` will send a link to videro's portfolios, I cant figure out how to do so, however, I know how to make `!vx portfolio @Videro` but I dont want the user to tag the member to get his/her portfolio, any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

I am using this but its not working-

```
async def portfolio(ctx, team_member):
    videro="videro"
    harxu="harxu"
    team_member = [videro,harxu,]
    videro_embed = discord.Embed(title=f"VX Videro", description=f"Here is Videro's Portfolio-"
                                                          f"\n:point_right: https://www.twitter.com/viderodzns", colour=0x40cc88)
    while True:
        if team_member=='videro':
            await ctx.send(embed=videro_embed)
```

Comment: The member converter should do this automatically.  Are you already using converters? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters

Comment: @PatrickHaugh , I am using the above code but its not working, I would really appreciate it If you could help me out in figuring this out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:  we have two commands, `register` and `portfolio`.  `register` saves a url, and `portfolio` will use those saves urls to create embeds.

```
from discord import Member, Embed

urls = {}

@bot.command()
async def register(ctx, member: Member, *, url):
    urls[str(member.id)] = url

@bot.command()
async def portfolio(ctx, member: Member):
    id = str(member.id)
    if id not in urls:
        await ctx.send(f"Unrecognized user {member.display_name}")
        return
    embed = Embed(title=f"VX {member.display_name}", 
              description=f"Here is {member.display_name}'s Portfolio-\n:point_right: {urls[id]}", colour=0x40cc88)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Hey there Patrick! The method you suggested works really well indeed, but I wanted to ask that is there any way by which we do not have to mention the member in order to see his/her portfolio? For example, I want the command to be `!vx portfolio videro` and not `!vx portfolio @videro`. Also, only if there is no easy way in which this is possible, Is there a way to permanently register a user from the user ID, as currently, whenever I make changes to the bot, I have to register all the members again. Thanks.

Comment: @Videro It should do that already, the `Member` converter can look people up by their name.  You can save the `urls` dict to a json file easily using the built in json library.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how json files work, can you please send an example of how exactly can I do that, or maybe you can send some references :)